# Launch Nokia Maps in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, launching-application, here-api

## Problem

I want to launch Nokia Maps inside Windows Phone 8 but I can't find the URI scheme which would allow me to do this.

Nokia Maps doesn't seem to listen to their REST Api or url either. (While this does work in Windows Phone, it's not using the Nokia Map it uses the browers)

My eventual goal is to figure out all the things Nokia Maps can do (X to Y, center on a gps coordinate, label locations, etc), and access them through app launching.

I originally tried the bingmaps URI scheme:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj635237.aspx

However this did not work, as Windows Phone 8 does not have Bing Maps, and does not listen to the old Bing Maps schema. I did try "nokiamaps:" but no luck :)

## Additional Information

In Windows Phone 8 it's pretty trivial to launch another app if you know the URI scheme:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh779672(v=win.10).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4

If I could find documentation on their schema I'd be set!

## TLDR

Can you solve the following problem: Fill in the empty string launchNokiaMaps to launch the Nokia Maps app.

```cs
private async void launch()
{
    string launchNokiaMaps = "";
    await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(launchNokiaMaps));
}
```

Comment: Can't you use the BingMapsTask? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.bingmapstask(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: I just tried it out and so far it seems good! I'll have to see if it will allow me to do X to Y, as there only appears to be a search term. I'll update the question after investigation, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After investigation, I found the Uri:

```
private async void launch()
{
    string launchNokiaMaps = "explore-maps://v1.0/?latlon=56.615495,12.1865081&zoom=5";
    await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(launchNokiaMaps));
}
```

That will lauch the Nokia Maps app.

However you should be careful with that because Nokia Maps is not necessarily installed on Windows Phone 8 devices. For example, HTC devices come with the default "Maps" app.

So if you just want to open the default Maps app, you should use the MapsTask. That will work on every Windows Phone 8 device.

Comment: Hi, Official Nokia Response: The aforementioned "explore-maps://v1.0" app2app custom protocol is NOT SUPPORTED for 3rd party apps. We will be potentially breaking it soon and all apps that use it will flat out stop working. Do not use the aforementioned protocol in your apps. As a workaround, please either use the new MapTasks or "ms-*" app2app custom protocols instead.  Sincerely, Justin Angel.

Comment: Hi Justin! Thanks for your response; I'll be using the MapTasks for now :) Nokia has great documentation, do you know if there is documentation available for the recommended way of launching Nokia Maps and Nokia Drive?

Comment: Or any specification on what can be supplied to ms-*. I found a lot of examples, but they only use "destination". And destination.name doesn't do a geo lookup (So unless I figure out the GPS of the Sears Tower I can't launch the maps app using ms-*, as far as I can tell so far)

Comment: To bad the new MapTask is a horrible inefficient API.

Comment: @JustinAngel, that was true. Now, `explorer-maps://` and `maps://` both launch **Bing maps** on Lumia devices, even Bing maps is removed from app list in Lumia devices! Perhaps it happened after gdr3 (Amber)? Can't go back to gdr2 to verify. Either way it means we have bing maps app on Lumia devices but its hidden. Which means its crazy! To verify, send yourself an email with `maps://london`. and open the link in your phone from email..

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any information on if Nokia Drive subscribes to the new App2app protocols. However, the nokia based maps application has a task launcher that lets you do quite a bit. (Bing Map Task is depreciated)

```
MapsTask mapsTask = new MapsTask();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206989(v=vs.105).aspx

I would suggest implementing your own map control using the Maps API and get full control over the user experience.

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!guide-to-the-maps.html

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8

Answer (score 1):

Nokia have recently introduced a set of APIs specifically to launch HERE Maps on the device, as well as HERE Drive and HERE Transit.

The [API documentation](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers.html) specifies the following use cases:

> HERE Launchers are simple to use APIs which enable you to launch
>   HERE applications from your own Windows Phone application, to perform
>   services provided by those applications.
>
> The API is compatible with Windows Phone 8 devices. Additionally the
>   API requires the HERE applications implementing the services being
>   present in the device. In case the API is used without the
>   implementing application being present in the device, then the user
>   will be forwarded to the Application store for obtaining the required
>   application.
>
> Currently there are three HERE applications which are providing the
>   services implemented in the HERE launchers API: HERE Maps, HERE Drive,
>   and HERE Transit.
>
> HERE Maps, Drive, and Public Transport are available worldwide on all
>   Nokia Lumia Phones, and they may be available for other Windows Phones
>   via Windows Phone store.

Code examples (covering use cases such as the one displayed below) can be found [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers/here-launchers-api-demo.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my blog I put some information that could be useful if you want to insert in your WP8 app the capability to start a navigation to a destination.

http://enzocontini.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/how-to-start-a-turn-by-turn-navigation-to-a-destination-from-your-windows-phone-app/

;-)
Enzo Contini