# Can I launch the ‘Storage check’ app developed by Nokia?

Tags: windows-phone-8

‘Storage check’ is an app developed by OEM Nokia. Does anyone know if there is a way I can launch it from my own 3rd party app?

[Link for Storage app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/storage-check/b4cf45cc-a355-40d2-8b74-51517a042a18)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if Nokia provided a URI Association in their app. Nokia has a listing [here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/URI_Association_Schemes_List) (see the table: Nokia URI Schemes) of their apps that have URI associations, I don't see the storage check app there, so I think that is an indication that they do not provide a URI Association for this particular app, and thus you would not be able to. You could ask them to do so, who knows your request may be acted upon.

Answer (score 2):

I have to inform that I didn't tried this before.

In Windows Phone 8, you can add a Extensions/Protocol element to your WMAppManifest to reserve a URI prefix that can then be launched from another app using the [Launcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/br241801.aspx) class & some more [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

If you know the URI of the app(that you are looking to open) you can do it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387265/launch-nokia-maps-in-windows-phone-8?rq=1)

Hope this helps.